# Symfony login form "use_referer" ignored / not working

Tags: ajax, symfony

When a user clicks navigates to a page where he needs to sign in for before he can access it Symfony will redirect the user to the login page, when the user has succesfully logged in he gets redirected to the requested page.

Now when a user navigates to the login page directly the user will be redirected to the homepage (by default) after a succesful login. My understanding is that you can use `use_referer` to prevent this kind of behaviour so that the user gets redirected to the page where he clicked on the login link. However, the following code doesn't seem to work:

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        provider: user_db
        form_login:
            use_referer: true  //use_referer TRUE
            login_path: /login/
            check_path: /login_check
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path: /logout/
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key: <random key here>
            lifetime: 2592000
            path: /.*
            domain: ~
        security: true
        anonymous: true
```

**login.html.twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="_password" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

---

**More information**

Symfony does a great job when you click on a page with restricted access link, however if there's a link which tries to get restricted data via AJAX it doesn't do anything, I can get the user to redirect to the login form (changing link if not logged in) but afterwards it gets forwarded to the homepage. There are 2 possible solutions for this (I hope)

1. Redirect the user back to the referer page after a succesful login
2. Redirect back to the referer page and fire the ajax call.

Obviously solution 2 is the preferred one but I haven't got a clue if this is possible or not?

Comment: Symfony 2.8.8 here, same issue.